# add in a Makefile.in a -DVARIABLE linux

Tags: c, autoconf, automake, libtool, gnu-make

I am trying to make a configure.ac + Makefile.in files I have. Everything is ok till at make:

Here I have:

```
usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 12
4-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

WHY?

In my Makefile.am I did include: `AM_CFLAGS = -DMAIN=1`

WHat am I doing wrong?

Thx

**PROBLEM SOLVED
I VE REPLACES AM_CFLAGS WITH FILE_NAME_CFLAGS!!**

Comment: as @leigh has pointed out you should vote up answers you like, and "accept" the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I've replaced `AM_CFLAGS` with `FILE_NAME_CFLAGS`.

Comment: actually you should use FILE_NAME_CPPFLAGS (since defines are flags for the preprocessor rather than the compiler)